# How to stop Timer after it has finished iterating an arraylist Java

Tags: java, arraylist, timer

I have this timer method:

```
public void setTimer(int seconds, String userName, String content) {
    Timer timer = new Timer();
    timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            setTweet(userName, content);
            System.out.println("tweet posteado cada 5 segs");
        }
    }, 0, (seconds*1000));       
}
```

the variable "content" is defined by an arraylist. How to start the timer, iterate thru the arraylist and stop the timer when it has finished?

EDIT: added arraylist:

```
public ArrayList<String> readSelectedExcel(File path){
    ArrayList<String> tweetsArray = new ArrayList<>();
    try{
        FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(path);
        XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(fileInputStream);
        XSSFSheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);
        sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);
        for (Row myrow : sheet) {
            for (Cell mycell : myrow) {
                tweetsArray.add(mycell.getStringCellValue());
            }
        }
    }catch (FileNotFoundException te) {
        te.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("Accounts.xlsx Not Found");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }  

    return tweetsArray;
}
```

Comment: I added the arraylist in the post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [schedule(TimerTask task, long delay)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html#schedule(java.util.TimerTask,%20long)) instead of `scheduleAtFixedRate(TimerTask task, long delay, long period)`.

Here is an example:

```
int seconds = 1;
for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++){
    setTimer(seconds * i, userName,list.get(i));
}

public void setTimer(int seconds, final String userName, final String content) {
         Timer timer = new Timer();
         timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
             @Override
             public void run() {
                 setTweet(userName, content);
                 System.out.println("tweet posteado cada 5 segs");
             }
         }, (seconds*1000));       
}
```

Comment: I tried the code but if i set the seconds value to 5 it waits 5 seconds and then prints all the array elements, I want it to print an array element, wait 5 seconds and then print the next array element and so on until the array is finished, any idea how to do that?

Comment: @DiegoBarrena The important part is `seconds+i`, I think you've missed that.

Comment: I added it inside the loop like this: setTweet.setTimer(seconds+i, user.getScreenName(),readSelectedExcel(path).get(i)); is the loop supposed to add 1 second between every print?

Comment: @DiegoBarrena Yes, the `seconds+i` adds one second between each task, from your comment it seems that you what `seconds * i` which will add a 5 seconds delay between each task if `seconds = 5`.

Answer (score 0):

If you keep a reference to your timer object. Then just check to see if your ararylist is empty and then call timer.cancel() https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html#cancel()